# Issue with appending and referencing

Tags: swift, swift3

Hi im having an issue with the following two lines of code below. Im trying to insert an item from items array to the checkout array and set its stock to 1. However, it is also setting the stock to 1 for the items array.
Can someone explain why?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = items[indexPath.item]
    //inventoryController?.showItemDetailForItem(item: item, index: indexPath.item)
    if item.stock != 0 {
        total += item.price //adding each item to cart adds its price to the checkout price
    for x in checkout {
        if item.name == x.name{
            print("before stock is \(item.stock)")
            x.stock += 1
            print("after stock is \(item.stock)")
            return
        } else{
            print("not equal")
        }
    }
        checkout.insert(item, at: 0) // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
        checkout[0].stock = 1 //THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS
    } else{
        print("Not enough stockempty")
    }
    print("stock is \(item.stock)")
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: this question is not understandable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "For some reason the labeled lines below are referencing both arrays" because checkout.insert and check["0"] both reference the same array...

Comment: Thats the issue and why i dont understand why its manipulating both the parent and child array.

Comment: Your updated question makes more sense now. Why does your array have a stock property?

Comment: And what do you mean by child and parent arrays? I see one array that contains some items.

Comment: Its an array of objects. Each object has a property called stock

Comment: i dont get it.. if item.name == x.name here you increment the stock of x.. in the end of for loop you insert the item.. why?

Comment: the parent array is the uicollectionview or this line     let item = items[indexPath.item]
. The child array is checkout

Comment: if the item already exists in the checkout array. instead of inserting the item, increment the already existing item's stock by 1

Comment: if the item is already there in the checkout array, then why are you adding it to the checkout array again?

Comment: But that means that they are two separate discrete arrays. Why are you calling them parent/child?

Comment: i'm not im incrementing the stock of it

Comment: i guess my terminology is wrong. the child array is populated with items from the parent array i'll change it

Comment: yes. you have to change it

Comment: fixed sorry about that

Comment: @ValerioZhang fixed it?

Comment: fixed the question not the actual problem

Comment: Can you show the initialization of your two arrays (and possibly where you are using them in meaningful ways)? I think we aren't getting the full picture.

Comment: yes. i still dont get what he's upto

Comment: The arrays are initialized globally they are of the same type

Comment: guys it's full of comments.. we should use chat.. i dont see the chat option.. can anyone move this discussion to chat?

Comment: how do we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` is obviously a **class**. A class is a *reference type*.

When you are going to append a reference type object to a collection type, only a pointer will be assigned and the reference counter of the original object will be incremented.

So changing the value of a property affects all occurrences of the item.

To prevent this behavior use a *value type* (a struct) or make a `copy` of the object

Comment: O, Ok. How do i make a copy?

Comment: You could use the `copy()` method of `NSObject` to make a copy. You need to cast the copied object down to the actual type.

Comment: right totally right! i knew there was some referencing going on. Thanks so much